# no real iAd content displayed in app

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, iad

I've integrated and activated iAd within my app. Apple' sample iad is diplaying while running app in simulator and on device.
App has already been uploaded via itunesconnect as a build for testing.

How can "real" ad be displayed in my app before submitting app to official app store in order to check which kind of ad is displayed?
How can you choose which content / type of ad should be displayed in your app?

Testing real iad content would be very helpful.

Thanks for any feedback.

Regards.
Simon

Comment: It will only ever show sample ads until your app is on the App Store and live.

Answer (score 0):

There will only be real iAds displayed, after your App is live on the app store.

But yes, you can restrict and exclude ads from specific competitors or unwanted advertisers. You can set it in your itunesconnect preferences in the [iAd module](https://iadworkbench.apple.com/app/?page=routing#routing).

Comment: Ok, but I do not want to promote my app via Workbench. I just want to integrated ad from others. Therefore no Workbench has been created and cannot be created before submitting app to official app store.

Answer (score 0):

Real iAds are only displayed in apps which are live on the App Store. You can potentially make your own iAd via iAd maker and test it that way in your app. But other than that, you will only see proper iAds in your app when it is live.

Its also worth taking into account that when your app goes live, it takes Apple a few days before they activate your app for iAds. So you won't see any iAds in your live app for the first few days.

Comment: You need to download the iAD producer. Just make your own test basic iAD and get your app to load that instead of the Apple test adverts. The Apple developer website has all the downloads you need.